# Typescript compiler noResolve option is not working

Tags: typescript

From the list of available [options](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options), the following is documented for the `noResolve` option:

```
--noResolve     Do not add triple-slash references or module import targets to the list of compiled files.
```

But it doesn't seem to work as it still includes the `/// <reference path... />` tags in the compiled .js files.

Am I doing something wrong or the option is not intended for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation does not talk about stripping of the triple-slash comments from `.ts` or `.js` files. The compiler only does not include files referenced via triple-slash comments to the list of compiled files.

You can have a look at the unit test `declarationEmit_invalidReference2.ts` to verify `tsc` compiler behavior:

- TS file: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/cases/compiler/declarationEmit_invalidReference.ts
- Generated JS file: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/baselines/reference/declarationEmit_invalidReference.js
- Symbols: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/baselines/reference/declarationEmit_invalidReference.symbols
- Types: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/baselines/reference/declarationEmit_invalidReference.types

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out for me as I didn't understood well what the option does.

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to close this post or to remove it entirely since it was just a misunderstanding from my side.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a downvote and it may help someone else. I don't see a downside in letting it here. However, it's your decision. ;)